# Get the result of AFNetworking response as JSON string array

Tags: ios, json, swift, afnetworking

I have been trying to get the response data from the web service as array of strings but i couldn't manage to do that, Alamofire didn't work properly and thats why im using AFNetworking. apparently the response comes back but in the failure block and i will print it as string to show that its returning data but as string not as array of strings.

Here is my code :

```
     let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer(readingOptions: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

//        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(array: ["text/plain", "text/html", "application/json"]) as Set<NSObject>
        manager.GET(url, parameters: nil, success: { (AFHTTPRequestOperation, ewsult) -> Void in
            print("doing the request")
//            print(AFHTTPRequestOperation)
//            print()
            }) { (operation, erropr) -> Void in
                print(operation.responseString)

//            print(erropr)
        }

    }
```

Here  is the response :

> Optional("Array\n(\n    [0] => Array\n        (\n            [name] =>
>   Apple Juice\n            [0] => Apple Juice\n        )\n\n    [1] =>
>   Array\n        (\n            [name] => Apple Juice\n            [0]
>   => Apple Juice\n        )\n\n    [2] => Array\n        (\n            [name] => DryClean\n            [0] => DryClean\n        )\n\n    [3]
>   => Array\n        (\n            [name] => DryClean\n            [0] => DryClean\n        )\n\n)\n
> \n**Warning**:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   **/home/thegapps/public_html/abualrob/HotelsSysAPI/index.php** on
>   line **150**
> \n")

In summary i just need to get the response as array of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u'd better provide the data.
AFNetworing will parse the JSON to a dict and use like

```
NSArray *dictArr = responseObject[@"mydata"];
```

My suggestion u should

1. access the datas directly from the browser (just type the source url and browser will show)
2. copy the datas to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ find out format issue